# RapidMiner not working

Tags: rapidminer

I asked this question in RM forum but no one answered. I Created SVM prediction model and it used to work until one day it suddenly give error "Cannot deliver AttributeWeights with parameter "kernel_type" set to "polynomial".  " Anybody knows what did I clicked wrong because I could not use RM to build any models anymore.

Comment: can you post a screen-shot of your process and your process xml?

Answer (score 0):

SVMs can generally only work with binary labels. Polynomial would indicate to me that you don't have a binary label.